# beforeRouteEnter function and Vuex problem

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In the quasar project, I have a Vuex function "asyncValidateToken" that checks whether the user is logged in to the system. It is located in the file "src/store/index.js". The file contains the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import { api } from 'boot/axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      isLogin: false
    },
    mutations: {
      changeIsLogin (state, payload) {
          state.isLogin = payload;
      }
    },
    actions: {
      asyncValidateToken: async (context, payload) => {
        await api.post('/accounts/token', '', {
          headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data == localStorage.userId) {
              context.commit('changeIsLogin', true);
              return true;
          } else {
              context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);
              return false;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
  })

  return Store
}
```

The page "Results.vue" where the route protection is used via the function "beforeRouteEnter"

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <div>
      <charts />
      <feedback />
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>


<script>
import Charts from 'src/components/Charts.vue'
import Feedback from 'src/components/Feedback.vue'
import store from 'src/store/index.js'

export default {
  name: 'Results',
  components: {
    Charts,
    Feedback
  },
  beforeRouteEnter (to, fromR, next) {
    if (store.dispatch('asyncValidateToken')) { 
      next();
    } else { this.$router.push('/login'); }
  }
}
</script>
```

I get an error "src_store_index_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.dispatch is not a function
at beforeRouteEnter (Results.vue?82a0:23)
at routeEnterGuard (vue-router.esm.js?85f8:2333)". The construction "this.$store.dispatch('asyncValidateToken')" also does not work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
store().dispatch('')
```

Why?

Because your `store.js` module is exporting a function as default, and it returns the store.